# phpadmin 1064 error UUID trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create the following trigger in PHP admin but get the following error. I've set delimiter to '`//`' but still no luck. Any help?

For your information the table is called '`users`' and I'm trying to add the `UUID` to the primary key '`user_id`'

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_id_users_insert BEFORE INSERT ON 'users'
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.user_id=UUID();
END;
```

> *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'
>   FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   SET NEW.user_id=UUID();
>   END' at line 1*

Comment: What does `UUID` do ?

Comment: Quoting `'users'` with single-quote `'` characters results in it being parsed as a string literal (which is not valid in the `ON` clause of a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement) rather than as an SQL object identifier (such as a table name, which is what MySQL expects to see) which, if quoted, must instead use the backtick `\`` character (or, alternatively, double-quote `"` characters if MySQL's [`ANSI_QUOTES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled).  See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491)

Comment: Thanks the backtick worked. This now has been answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting 'users' with single-quote ' characters results in it being parsed as a string literal (which is not valid in the ON clause of a CREATE TRIGGER statement) rather than as an SQL object identifier (such as a table name, which is what MySQL expects to see) which, if quoted, must instead use the backtick ` character (or, alternatively, double-quote " characters if MySQL's ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled). See When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?  -- @eggyal

Comment: Fair enough...  I voted to close as "simple typographical error" instead.

Comment: @eggyal, me too.  But ya know, SO works better for folks when answers are answers, rather than comments. Even if they're community-wiki answers.